# How to set selection with expandablelistview in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to let the the item of expandablelistview which I clicked scroll to the head postion of the layout.But if I use setSelectedChild or setSelectedGroup ,the item can't scroll accurated.It sometimes scrolls more or less.So I want to now is there any way to make this come true?